# Sidebar Div Pushing Main Navigation Down

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, visual-glitch

I can't seem to figure this one out... I've been trying lots of different "solutions" I've found online and none of them seem to be doing it.

I have 2 divs. One is 200px Wide (the sidebar) the other is 800px wide (the main content) but when I float them both to the left some bad mojo goes down and they stack like the stair step glitch...

Also, the whole wooden background div is getting forced over 200pixels somewhere too... :(

Any ideas?

Here's the URL.

Main is http://www.glacierspringsadventures.com/httpdocs/
CSS is /css/style.css">http://www.glacierspringsadventures.com/httpdocs//css/style.css

Answer (score 0):

Alright guys! I figured it out.. well.. kinda.. It's working now...

I dropped a total of 10 pixels in the width. 5 on the  and 5 in the main content.

That apparently fixed it because it's floating and there is happiness. :D

Thanks anyway for the help!!